# MS-Access list box not updating based on conditional

Tags: sql, ms-access, listbox

I have Form!Main in access with 3 list boxes(choose a report, choose a cohort, choose a year) that grab data from the following respective tables (x_report_box, x_cohort_box, x_year_box).

The second box is populated based off the selection in the first box. 
Consequently, the third box is populated based off the selection in the second box.

The second box gets populated just fine once I make a selection in the first box. However, the third box stays blank after I make a selection in the second box.

In the first box under the property sheet in the AfterUpdate I've added a Me.List2.Requery As well as for the second box Me.List3.Requery.

The code I used to populate the second box was

```
SELECT coh.cohort_name
FROM x_cohort_box AS coh
WHERE (((coh.report_id)=[Forms]![Main]![List1]));
```

The code I used to populate the third box was

```
SELECT yr.year_name
FROM x_year_box AS yr
WHERE (((yr.cohort_id)=[Forms]![Main]![List2]));
```

[image]

[image]

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is the bound column on the second list box set correctly? Do you receive results when running the query manually whilst the form is open?

Comment: Do you mean the Requery is in the VBA event procedure associated with the event property? Need to Requery the third listbox in event code for second listbox. Cascading listbox/combobox is a common topic.

Comment: Yes, I requery the third listbox one I make a selection on the second listbox if that's waht you mean